# Multiply items in stream

Tags: java, java-stream

Is it possible with Java stream API to duplicate items a few times?

For instance let's say we have a list of orders where each order has a product code and quantity. I want to get a list of product codes which contains n copies of the given code where n is the quantity.

When I got 2 orders `("product1" : 3x, "product2": 2x)` I want in result a list like this: `("product1", "product1", "product1", "product2", "product2")`

Is there a pretty way to do that with streams without the old `for` cycle?

Code looks like this:

```
@Data
public class OrderRow {
   private String productCode;

   private int quantity;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` with `Collections.nCopies` as :

```
public static List<String> products(List<OrderRow> orderRows) {
    return orderRows.stream()
            .flatMap(o -> Collections.nCopies(o.quantity, o.productCode).stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`Stream.flatMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) and create a new stream with the items for each row:

```
List<String> result = orderRows.stream()
        .flatMap(row -> Stream.generate(row::getProductCode).limit(row.getQuantity()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You also can use this:

```
List<String> result = orderRows.stream()
        .flatMap(row -> IntStream.range(0, row.getQuantity()).mapToObj(i -> row.getProductCode()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```